# Where do you use Fortran block?

Tags: fortran

Fortran 2008 introduces the keyword `block` to define a new scope where new local variables can be declared.
I use `block` only when I need to add temporary diagnostic codes in an existing program.
Are there are other settings that make `block` useful?

Comment: As I don't know if openmp supports this yet a comment rather than an answer - block and omp parallel regions would go together quite nicely, using the new scope to declare all the private variables you need during the region.